# How to use Jooq for a table that doesn't exist yet?

Tags: java, jooq

I have a database (postgresql) with a Table Cdr. Every month a new table is created in the database that has the same schema as Table Cdr, named Cdr__ (eg. Cdr_2016_04).

I'm trying to use Jooq to query the database, based on a date provided. The trouble is that:

```
context.select(CDR.fields())
            .from("cdr_2017_01")
            .where(CDR.FIELD1.eq("somevalue")
                .and(CDR.FIELD2.notEqual("value 2")
                .and(CDR.FIELD2.notEqual("value 3")))
            .fetchInto(Cdr.class);
```

doesn't work because it indicates that

> org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: ...from cdr_2017_01 where ("public"."cdr"."field1" = ? and "public"."cdr"."field2" <> ? and "public"."cdr"."field2" <> ?)]; ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "cdr"

I've tried using an alias to make it 'cdr_2017_01 as cdr', but that fails because cdr already exists.  It seems that because I use CDR.FIELD1, and CDR.fields(), jooq requires that the table in the from clause be CDR. Is there some way to make this generic, or should I not be using Jooq for this kind of query?

Comment: Try `.from("\"cdr_2017_01\"")`.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work, same error as before ... from "cdr_2017_01" where ... ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "cdr"

Comment: What type of exception produces the error string?

Comment: It's a org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException, I've updated the question with that info as well.

Comment: Aw, it's an SQL syntax error - you can't `SELECT` columns from a table not specified in the `FROM` clause, like you've established yourself. I'm sure there's a nice way to alias the result columns but I don't think there is one elegant in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The error

The error you're getting originates from your usage of the generated `CDR` literal in your field references, e.g. `CDR.FIELD1`. All these fields will be fully qualified with the `"cdr"` table, not the `"cdr_2017_01"` table that you put in the from clause.

You can turn on [debug logging](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/logging) to see formatted SQL strings that jOOQ generates and sends to the server.

#### A workaround

The simplest workaround is to alias your `"cdr_2017_01"` table back to `"cdr"` like this:

```
context.select(CDR.fields())
        .from("cdr_2017_01 as cdr")
        .where(CDR.FIELD1.eq("somevalue")
            .and(CDR.FIELD2.notEqual("value 2")
            .and(CDR.FIELD2.notEqual("value 3")))
        .fetchInto(Cdr.class);
```

This will work to some extent with most queries.

#### A better solution

You should use the [runtime schema / table mapping feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/runtime-schema-mapping/) for this. It is designed exactly for these kinds of multi-tenancy / partitioning use-cases.

You can then write something along the lines of:

```
DSL.using(connection, new Settings()
       .withRenderMapping(new RenderMapping()
           .withSchemata(new MappedSchema()
               .withInput("my_schema_name")
               .withTables(new MappedTable()
                   .withInput(CDR.getName())
                   .withOutput(CDR.getName() + "_2017_01")))))
   .select(CDR.fields())
   .from(CDR)
   .where(CDR.FIELD1.eq("somevalue")
       .and(CDR.FIELD2.notEqual("value 2")
       .and(CDR.FIELD2.notEqual("value 3")))
   .fetchInto(Cdr.class);
```

Another option, of course, might be to use PostgreSQL's partitioning feature, in case of which you might not need to explicitly specify table names in the client:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html